# Why doesn't my jquery selector work here?

Tags: jquery, qtip

I'm creating a little dynamic tooltip function.

Basically if I have a link like so:

```
<a href="#" data="xyz">?</a>
```

Using qTip, I attempt to lookup a tooltip table in mysql and retrieve the tip based on the data in the data attribute.

So:

```
$('a[data]').qtip({ 
    content: {
       url: '/tooltip.php',
       data: { tipKey: $(this).attr('data') },
       method: 'post'
}
});
```

Problem is, it doesn't work. $(this).attr('data') doesn't seem to pull the value inside the attribute.

If I manually change the function so it looks like the following it works no problem.

```
    $('a[data]').qtip({ 
    content: {
        url: '/tooltip.php',
        data: { tipKey: 'xyz' },
        method: 'post'
    }

});
```

What am I missing when I'm trying to pull the data from the data attribute? Should I be doing something like:

```
    $('a[data]').qtip({ 
    content: {
        url: '/tooltip.php',
        data: { tipKey: ''+$(this).attr('data')+'' },
        method: 'post'
    }

});
```

As that isn't yielding the value either!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't works because the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/this_Operator) keyword represents the context of the function that is being executed, and you are using it inside an object literal.

For example, if you execute your snippet in the `$(document).ready` event, the `this` keyword will represent the document element.

You could [iterate](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each) over your selector and initialize each element tooltip individually:

```
$('a[data]').each(function () {
  var $link = $(this);
  $link.qtip({ 
      content: {
        url: '/tooltip.php',
        data: { tipKey: $link.attr('data') },
        method: 'post'
      }
  });
});
```

Also note that the `data` attribute is not standard, your page will not pass the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: thanks heaps CMS... i've shifted from 'data' to 'title' and your solution worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

This example works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Text</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  alert($("a[data]").text());
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" data="123">abc</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well he's looking for getting the attribute, not the text of the link right?

Comment: Correct Alberto... the attr not the stuff inbetween the <a></a>

Answer (score 1):

You should try accessing the 0th element of data. Like this:

```
data: { tipKey: $("a[data]")[0].data},
```

EDIT: oh ok, i see, this should work then as an alternative.